# Access dynamic id in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In html i have a div

```
<div class="row"  id='textdrag{{$index}}'>
```

I need to use the id to display context menu based on id,like.

```
$("#textdrag2").contextmenu(function (event) {  
    setcontextposition("text");
});
```

But for some reason the context menu is not displayed.

Its works just fine when i just use id="textdrag" without the $index

Comment: Did you try what is the value of `$index`? Just print it outside of your div `{{$index}}`, seems like it is an empty value

Comment: i specifically know $index value to be 2. As seen on the elements of dev tools

Comment: When you inspect this html element what do you see as the id

Comment: It is showing textdrag2

Comment: When are you binding this contextmenu event handler ?

Comment: Its working now when i am using class instead of id. Contextmenu was showing only to the first index before now its showing to all index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you append to the class instead and that way you wont have a flaky selector on a dynamic id. It is generally not a good idea to use a selector that will change.

```
<div class="row text-drag-cls"  id='textdrag{{$index}}'>

$(".text-drag-cls").contextmenu(function (event) {  
    setcontextposition("text");
 });
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to the following

```
<div class="row" id="{{ 'textdrag' + $index }}"></div>
```

Comment: When are you binding this `contextmenu` event handler ?

Comment: Yes, its working now if i am using class instead of id

Answer (score 0):

## Why it isn't working by current approach?

Basically your javascript is getting fire as soon as it loads, but that instance `textdrag{{$index}}` haven't evaluated `$index` value. Since the event haven't got attached to that DOM.

---

I'd rather recommend you to create directive for this functionality, which generally viable solution to play with DOM in AngularJS. By this approach you don't need to specify unique identifier to each element.

```
<div class="row" context-menu>
   ...
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('contextMenu', [function(){
   return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         element.contextmenu(function (event) {  
            setcontextposition("text");
         });
      }
   }
}])
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining, directive is one viable option. My code it working now without using $index as i used class instead of id.